# Reasons for using C++/CLI instead of c#?

Tags: c++-cli

I wrote a managed C++ application a few years ago. It was just a personal project and I chose managed c++ just because I found it interesting. I remember it felt like it just took a lot more time than doing c# and there wasn't anything to gain from it in my case at least.

When is C++/CLI a good choice in reality?
What is it's benefits?

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933210/c-cli-why-should-i-use-it, which gave a better answer than I did

Comment: This is a closer dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874783/what-are-the-situations-or-pros-and-cons-to-use-of-c-cli-over-c

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886881/c-cli-advantages-over-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297323/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-c-cli-over-either-standard-c-or-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason for using C++/CLI is so you can use a native library in a managed application. Even Microsoft says it shouldn't be used on its own:

> The second major consideration for using C++/CLI is to remember that
>   this is only intended to be a bridge between the managed and native
>   worlds and not intended to be a technology you use to write the bulk
>   of your application. It is certainly possible to do so, but you'll
>   find that developer productivity is much lower than in a pure C++ or
>   pure C#/Visual Basic environment and that your application runs much
>   slower to boot. So when you use C++/CLI, compile only the files you
>   need with the /clr switch, and use a combination of pure managed or
>   pure native assemblies to build the core functionality of your
>   application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315414.aspx#id0070020

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

For me, it's far less difficult to write managed code in C#, but sometimes the performance that C++ offers makes it a better choice. I write the performance-critical code in c++, and the rest in C#. The only reason for C++/CLI is so that the native code and managed code can be used together.

Herb Sutter's design rational:

> C++/CLI’s mission is to provide direct access for C++ programmers to use existing CLI libraries and create new ones, with little or no performance overhead, with the minimum amount of extra notation, and with full ISO C++ compatibility.

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/C++CLIRationale.pdf